# Can't unschedule propagation (Oracle AQ)

Tags: sql, oracle, queuing

I've set up a queue in Oracle DB, been using it for a while, but then propagation (to a remote server) stopped working and now suddenly any manipulation hangs: I can't disable/unschedule propagation, can't stop/drop the queue itself. The queries just hang for hours. How do I purge the thing?